# Comando Powershell Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter para pesquisa de todos os usuários fora de um grupo

Tags: filter, powershell, ad

Qual o comando para pesquisar todos os usuários do domínio que não pertençam à um certo GG?

já tentei usando:
`Get-ADUser -ldapfilter {(&(name*)(!memberof=*GG_DI-ADM))} -properties * | select name, samaccountname, enabled`

O negócio é que no GG possuem 30 pessoas e quando pesquiso sem a condição negativa não aparece ninguém. Quando coloco igual ao código acima aparecem todos os usuários sem restringir o grupo.

Comment: O que é esse GG?

Comment: uma pasta de rede que somente usuários da informática possuem